# Facebook in PHP - Procedure

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook is usually used to login in multiple websites (including StackOverflow) but I would like to use it to make a simple voting system throw PHP using MySQL, using the Facebook ID has an identifier to avoid double votes. That's my rate.php file:

```
<?php
    function get_my_db() {
        static $db;

        if (!$db) {
            $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'table');
        }

        return $db;
    }

    session_start();
    // added in v4.0.0
    define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
    require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php' );
    //require 'functions.php';
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
    // init app with app id and secret
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '*******','*******' );
    // login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("http://mywebsite.com/rate.php");
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
        // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
    // see if we have a session
    if (isset($session)) {            
        // graph api request for user data
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        // get response
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');         // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $fbmail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
        /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $fbmail;

        <MySQL procedures>

        session_unset();
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = NULL;
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = NULL;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  NULL;
    } else {
        header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
    }
?>
```

Instead of making the changes asked in the MySQL procedure, it doesn't even pass throw the `if (isset($session))` condition (I've removed the `header("Location: ".$loginUrl);`, inserted an echo after the condition, and had no return), starting an infinite loop. I've used many websites has reference and nothing worked to me until now.

I also need that this page gets closed after realizing the MySQL procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is still wandering and looking for an answer to that question, this is what I did: I've used the old facebook-php-sdk, which can be found here:

> https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk

With the three files inside the /src folder, you just need to create your own files: one to use their resources to perform a Facebook login, and the other one to perform your own procedures. This is my file, a bit modified to explain how to use it.

In order to use it, you should call **destination.php** (you can name it however you want, just remember to update the code). If the user is already logged in and has gave your app authorization, then your procedures will be executed directly. Otherwise, **fbmain.php** will request the user to login and then redirect back to **destination.php**.

**fbmain.php:**

```
<?php

    $fbconfig['appid' ]     = "your app id";
    $fbconfig['secret']     = "your app secret";
    $fbconfig['baseurl']    = "destination.php url";

    $user = null; 
    try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        error_log($o);
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    // Facebook Authentication part
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => '',  // Things you want to retrieve from your user; in my case I just wanted the FB identifier, so the field could be left blank
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']  // Remember to add the GET arguments here in case you have any; otherwise you will lost them after the user login
        )
    );

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } 
      catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    if ($user){
        // Get user basic description
        $userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user");
    }
?>
```

**destination.php**

```
<?php
    include_once "fbmain.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Working...</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- all time check if user session is valid or not -->
    <?php
        if ($user){
            $fbid = $userInfo["id"]; // This is the FB identifier

            // Do your stuff here

            // When you finish, clean everything
            $user = null;
            $userinfo = null;
            $user_profile = null;
            $fbid = null;

            ?>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
                self.close();
            </script>

            <?php
        } else {
            ?>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              window.onload = function(){
                window.location="<?=$loginUrl?>";
              }
            </script>

            If you wasn't automatically redirected, click <a href="<?=$loginUrl?>">here</a>.
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is based in the Facebook SDK codes made by Mahmud Ahsan (http://thinkdiff.net), however I don't which one exactly (he made many, and I've made that code almost one year ago; sorry).

In case someone find a solution to do that using the latest Facebook SDK that would be great, however this is the only method I've managed to do it for now.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with your code it seems as calling `$helper->getLoginUrl()` when the user has been authenticated and is redirected back to rate.php causes your problem.

You need to determine if the request to rate.php is the user being redirect back to rate.php from Facebook.

Facebook redirects back to rate.php with a *code* in the URL. Only call `$helper->getLoginUrl()` if the user is not authenticated and no code is in the URL. Meaning that the request is not a redirect from Facebook.

```
if(!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($session) ){
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(); 
    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

You should probably add that condition after your `try catch` and before the `if(isset($session))` line. Remove the `else` at the bottom.

Comment: When you say _top part of you code_, do you mean above the `if (isset($session)) {` or above the `session_start();`?

Comment: Didn't worked. Put above the `if (isset($session)) {` and now it returns me `http://mywebsite.com/rate.php` as a blank page with a `code` and a `status` as GET arguments. No error output, but it doesn't even get inside the  `if (isset($session)) {` (I've put an `echo "Working";` as the first line inside it and still no return).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer. I replaced `!isset($_SESSION['FBID'])` with `!isset($session)`. You should add the code after your `try catch` statement and before the `if(isset($session))` line.

Comment: The position is exactly where I supposed. Unfortunately, it still has the same error. No error output, and it still didn't even get inside the `if (isset($session)) {`.

Comment: [Try this](http://pastie.org/10028407), the difference is that I use composer to load Facebook PHP SDK. You could replace the `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` with your `require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php' );` but I really recommend that you start using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: `Sorry, there is no pastie #10028407 or it has been removed.`